# Can I apply "writeBufferHighWaterMark" option to "OioClientSocketChannel"?

Tags: java, netty

I'm in trouble to solving a server problem. 
When the connections growing too much to endure, the number of 'CLOSE_WAIT' status connections is increasing sharply.

I've searched the solution of this problem and found a tip. 
(http://web.archiveorange.com/archive/v/ZVMdIdpQAlQ0ELH4D8SH)

In above page trustin,Lee guides us to use 'writeBufferHighWaterMark' option when connection set up.

```
    clientBootstrap.setOption("writeBufferHighWaterMark", 4096);
    clientBootstrap.setOption("writeBufferLowWaterMark", 1024);
```

I'm wondering that if this option is valid to oioSocketChannel. 
All of examples related it using nioSocketChannel.

Thanks for your kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not applicable for OIO. Note that the water mark mechanism control memory consumption that is due to many asynchronous writes; OIO uses blocking IO all over.